# pm2-windows-startup stopped working after Windows reinstallation

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I use PM2 module and pm2-windows-startup utility to automatically run Node.js when Windows startups. It was working perfectly during a few months, but recently once I reinstalled my Windows, the utility stopped working.

When I run Node by command promt with

`pm2 start myapp.js --watch`

I get the message

> PM2 is being successfully deamonized

Then if I run the command

`pm2-startup install`

I get

> Successfully added PM2 startup registry entry.

And then if I run

`pm2 save`

I get

> PM2 is being successfully deamonized
>
> Saving current process list...
>
> Nothing to save !!!

But if I restart my computer, the utility doesn't start Node.js

How to resolve the problem?